# GLFW3 Error - "WGL: Failed to find a suitable pixel format"

Tags: c, windows, opengl, mingw, glfw

I'm trying to get GLFW3 working on my Windows 8 machine with MinGW, but with little success. I have this test program copied straight from the GLFW documentation (with a bit of editing to make it work with the shared library) that I'm trying to run:

```
#define GLFW_DLL

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void error_callback(int error, const char* description)
{
    fputs(description, stderr);
}

static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;
    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);
    if (!glfwInit())
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Simple example", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        float ratio;
        int width, height;
        glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
        ratio = width / (float) height;
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(-ratio, ratio, -1.f, 1.f, 1.f, -1.f);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glRotatef((float) glfwGetTime() * 50.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glColor3f(1.f, 0.f, 0.f);
        glVertex3f(-0.6f, -0.4f, 0.f);
        glColor3f(0.f, 1.f, 0.f);
        glVertex3f(0.6f, -0.4f, 0.f);
        glColor3f(0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
        glVertex3f(0.f, 0.6f, 0.f);
        glEnd();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Like I said, I compiled GLFW as a shared library, and I have the glfw3.dll file in the same folder as the rest of my code. It compiles fine, but when I run the program I get a "WGL: Failed to find a suitable pixel format" error. Apparently, this can have to do with video card drivers, but I've updated mine, and I still get the same error.
It might help to know that I have an Nvidia 720M and an Intel HD Graphics 4000 card, with Optimus switching between the two. I tried running the program with both of them and got the same error.

EDIT: I should probably also show you how I'm building it

```
gl-test: main.c
    gcc -o gl-test main.c -lopengl32 -lglfw3dll
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same problem. Just to clarify, you want me to add "-lgdi32" to my Makefile, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my problem didn't have to do with my drivers at all. Instead, I was simply compiling GLFW3 incorrectly.

My suggestion to those facing the same problem as me: Remember to actually build GLFW as a shared library if you want it that way! The variable is called `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS`. If you're using cmake-gui, changing that is pretty simple (Just make sure to press configure again to save your changes, which is what I didn't do). Otherwise, you need to add `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=on` when running cmake in the terminal.